# Monitoring the process in python

Tags: python, polling, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto to open a application and closing the dialogue box.
I am able to do that but i want to check for the dialogue box from the time I start the application until the app closes..what is the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide contains all necessary methods: [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html). What you need is method `dialog_spec.wait_not('exists', timeout=20)` which waits till dialog is closed during 20 seconds.